# C# - If em ComboBox Exercício Caelum

Tags: c#, if, combobox

Boa tarde pessoal, já estou há algumas horas tentando resolver esse exercício da apostila de C# da Caelum, porém acredito estar longe de resolver. Gostaria de saber como faço para usar um IF dentro de um ComboBox para fazer ele distinguir entre uma conta corrente e uma conta poupança na hora de criação da conta. Segue o código que consegui produzir até agora. Este é o código somente do form de cadastro. No form principal está tudo ok até agora hehe... 
Esta é a pergunta em si do exercício: ***No formulário de cadastro, adicione um combo box (chamado comboTipoConta) que permita
a escolha do tipo de conta que será cadastrado.***
desde já agradeço.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Banco1
{

    public partial class FormCadastroConta : Form
    {
        private Form1 formPrincipal;

        public ComboBox tipoConta { get;  set; }

        public FormCadastroConta(Form1 formPrincipal)
        {
            this.formPrincipal = formPrincipal;
            InitializeComponent();
            comboTipoConta.Items.Add("Corrente");
            comboTipoConta.Items.Add("Poupança");
        }
        public FormCadastroConta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void botaoCadastro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public void comboTipoConta_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(comboTipoConta.Items.Add("Corrente")))
            {
                ContaCorrente novaConta = new ContaCorrente();
                novaConta.Titular = new Cliente(textoTitular.Text);
                novaConta.Numero = Convert.ToInt32(textoNumero.Text);
                this.formPrincipal.AdicionaConta(novaConta);

            }
            else if (Convert.ToBoolean(comboTipoConta.Items.Add("Poupança")))
            {
                ContaPoupança novaConta = new ContaPoupança();
                novaConta.Titular = new Cliente(textoTitular.Text);
                novaConta.Numero = Convert.ToInt32(textoNumero.Text);
                this.formPrincipal.AdicionaConta(novaConta);

            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Duvido que dê para ajudar sem saber exatamente o que é para fazer, mas de qualquer forma eu vejo vários erros neste código, muitos que parecem corretos, que são os mais perigosos.

Comment: da um desconto to começando agora kkkkk o que não ficou claro pq da pra saber o q tenho q fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como maniero citou, tá bem complicado isso aí... kkkk, tens que entender o que faz cada código. Tentar te ajudar:

`comboTipoConta_SelectedIndexChanged` é um evento, ou seja, esse código vai ser executado quando o `Index` selecionado do combo for alterado. É isso que você precisa? Não! rsrs pode remover esse código...

Agora, no botão "Cadastrar", aí sim você tem que criar a conta, correto ?

então deveria fazer:

> Considerando que a posição 0, será sempre referente a conta corrente, e posição 1 será poupança, e que somente haverá essas duas posições:

```
 private void botaoCadastro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex ==0)
      {
         //cadastra conta corrente
      }
      else
      {
         //cadastra conta poupança
      }

     this.Close();
 }
```

Está bem simples, mais pra que você tente entender, sem entrar nos outros problemas que o código tem

Comment: Antes estava no botão cadastrar mas aí tirei pois desse jeito começou a dar um pouco certo. Porém eu via que estava na gambiarra rsrs... pelo que você mostrou deu pra entender. Vou tentar aqui. Valeu demais cara.

Comment: Deu certo, assim que eu vi o comboTipoConta.SelectedIndex ==0 lembrei que eles sempre começam do zero... Se não fosse você estava ferrado. Valeuuuuuuuu.

Comment: se resolveu seu problema, mesmo que pontual, marque a resposta por favor =]